# How can use Jetty JNDI for DAO Junit testing in core java?

Tags: java, junit, jetty, datasource, jndi

i make a rest service and test for use postman then data save easily in data bese where i am using Jetty server with JNDI now i am trying  junit test dao as well rest post service but when i run junit then it is unable to hit database its seems like unable to find jndi.

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow. Make sure to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem you're describing.

Comment: Formatted the error trace